# How do I run my discord.py Bot on a server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-venv

I coded my own discord bot using discord.py and on my own pc it runs perfectly fine but now I want to run it on a server which I have remote access too. It just uses normal windows. I installed python 3.12.0 on it. When I try to execute the file via powershell it gives me the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'" because my first line is import discord.

I installed discord.py through powershell with pip install discord.py but still the same error :/ Any help would be much acpreciated! Is it maybe because my code uses a venv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your code on the server uses a venv as you said, you can try this:

- In explorer, go into the directory where your virtual environment is installed
- In that directory, go to the "Scripts" folder, and copy the file path
- In PowerShell, paste it and type the following (don't use the brackets):

```
(your path)\python.exe -m pip install discord.py
```

Now it should have installed in the venv, if you have any more issues I can help